# how do i fix my cellular automaton using a nested loop in python

Tags: python, function, matrix, nested

Most of the game of life example codes I've seen online have used class and boolean maths (true/false). Instead of this, I have attempted to create one function that iterates over each cell in the matrix and then updates the whole matrix according to the rules of the game, then returns the new matrix. The reason for this is because for my project I will be using pre-prepared input data that are the same size matrixs.

I think this may be currently updating each cell as it goes along and also instead of all cells being only alive (1) or dead (0) it returns values like 118 for example.

An example input data is shown bellow:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

this is my attempt so far... 
i think my issue is with the data type that is in the matrix (numpy int) - in one case i have to add them to find the number of neighbough cells (this determines whether the cell lives of dies after the next tick or generation) and in another i just want to re-write 1 or 0 in the new matix (in same position as input matrix cell in question) based on the neighbough of that cell in the input.

here is my attempt

```
def tick(matrix):
    new_state = np.empty_like(matrix)
    for i in range(17):
        for j in range(17):
            north = matrix[i][j-1]
            south = matrix[i][j+1]
            west = matrix[i+1][j]
            east = matrix[i-1][j]
            se = matrix[i+1][i+1]
            sw = matrix[i+1][i-1]
            ne = matrix[i-1][i+1]
            nw = matrix[i-1][i-1]
            neibours = np.sum([north, south, west, east, se, sw, ne, nw])
            if matrix[i][j] == '0' and neibours == 3:
                new_state [i][j] == '1'
            if matrix[i][j] == '1' and neibours<2:
                new_state [i][j] == '0'
            if matrix[i][j] == '1' and  neibours>4:
                new_state [i][j] == '0'
            if matrix[i][j] == '1' and neibours==2 or 3:
                new_state [i][j] == '1'
            return new_state

world2 = np.loadtxt('data/Loaf.txt',dtype=np.int8)
world3 = np.loadtxt('data/Pentadecathlon.txt',dtype=np.int8)        
world1 = np.loadtxt('data/Pulsar.txt',dtype=np.int8)
l = tick(world1)

print(l)
```

I think i will also need to add some condition that deals with elements on the edge of the matrix that don' have a full set of neighbors. I am really lost as to how I would do this in my function.

Comment: Your matrix is numerical, but you are comparing numbers to characters like '0' and '1'. To take into account the edges of the matrices, you can read the different directions conditionally for example: north = (matrix[i][j-1] if j>0 else 0).

Comment: thanks, even if I change '1' to 1 it is only returning an output that's identical to the input. the edge condition works well tho !

Comment: Also remember to use numbers in the new_state (set to 1/0 not '1'/'0'). You can debug the routine by placing prints inside the if statements to see if they are actually evaluated. If not, print matrix[i][j] and other conditions to see why they don't get modified

Comment: so print statements inside if statements (within the function) are not affecting the output at all (and indeed not printing)... I presume this means its never getting to the if statements and just returning the new state the same as the old state. Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Your return statement is also indented two layers too deep. It returns immediately after checking the cell (0,0).